# Does not work model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

Tell me with this question. Create a model and a migration:

```
class CreateSmsSends < ActiveRecord::Migration

def up
create_table :sms_sends do |t|

  t.integer :issue_number

  t.string :sms_number

  t.text :sms_text

  t.boolean :send

  t.boolean :deliver

  t.timestamps

end

end

def down
  drop_table :sms_sends
end
end
```

Model:

```
class SmsSend < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :issue_number, :sms_number, :sms_text, :send, :deliver
end
```

I'm trying to do in the console:

```
> s = SmsSend.new
=> #<SmsSend id: nil, issue_number: nil, sms_number: nil, sms_text: nil, send: nil, deliver: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
> s.issue_number = 1
```

It gives this:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
from /home/redmine_dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@redmine320/gems/activerecord- 4.2.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:48:in `__temp__3756e646'
from /home/redmine_dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@redmine320/gems/activerecord- 4.2.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:379:in `clone_attribute_value'
```

If I try this:

```
 s = SmsSend.new(issue_number: 12345, sms_number: '9865654697', sms_text: 'text', send: 0, deliver: 0)
```

It gives this:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
from /home/redmine_dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@redmine320/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/before_type_cast.rb:47:in `read_attribute_before_type_cast'
from /home/redmine_dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@redmine320/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:160:in `block in original_raw_attribute'
```

Please tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're breaking things terribly by defining a `send` column on your model.

The `send` method is used to send messages to Ruby objects. It's a fundamental part of Ruby, and a part that ActiveRecord obviously depends on. Your column name is clobbering that method and making it unavailable on instances of your model.

Rename your `send` column to something that doesn't clash with a built-in method name.